# A Proto-theorem about superconductivity

Tags: superconductivity

**Background**

There are two key assumptions which are used in the Ginzburg Landau model, in light of the BCS Hamiltonian on a 2-manifold $\Sigma$:
$$H_\text{BCS}=\int_\Sigma D_i\psi^\dagger D^i\psi\, d^2x+\frac{1}{2}\int_{\Sigma^2}V \psi^\dagger \psi^\dagger \psi\,\,\psi\,\, d^4x.$$
These assumptions use two formal quantities, which I will define here:
$$F_\text{GL}(\psi,\mathbf A)=\int_{\Sigma} (D_i\phi^\dagger \,D^i\phi +F_{ij}F^{ij}+\alpha|\phi |^2+\beta|\phi|^4)\,d^2x$$
$$\tilde{F}_\text{GL}(\phi,A)=\int_{\Sigma\times \mathbb R} (D_\mu \phi^\dagger \,D^\mu \phi+F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}+\alpha|\phi|^2+\beta|\phi|^4)\,d^3x$$

My question is, are these two assumptions equivalent? Or do they need independent justification?:

1. **Mean Field Theory usage:** According to this assumption, $F_\text{GL}(\phi,A)$ is the free energy of a mean-field approximation $$H_\text{MF}(\phi)=\int D_i(\psi^\dagger D^i\psi+ \phi\,\psi\psi+h.c.)$$
   to $H_\text{BCS}$. In other words, we minimize $F_\text{GL}$ to find the best non-interacting approximation to $H_\text{BCS}$.
2. **Effective Field Theory usage:** According to this assumption, $\tilde{F}_\text{GL}(\phi,A)$ is the action for an effective field theory which is a Wilsonian RG scaling limit of the quantum field theory described by $H_\text{BCS}$. In other words, minimizing $\tilde{F}_\text{GL}$ represents the semi-classical limit of this effective field theory.

**Closing Remarks:**

Finally, how hard is it to show that they are consistent? If they are consistent, then can we make cross-statements like

> **Proto-theorem:** The solutions to
> $$\delta F_\text{GL}(\psi,A)|_{T=0}=\delta E_\text{GL}^\text{ground}(\psi,A)=0$$ represent quantum field-theoretic ground states of the effective field theory $\tilde{F}_\text{GL}(\psi,A)$.

Comment: Completely unintelligible question. Well, I'm not even sure there is a question.

Comment: Are both uses of the Ginzburg-Landau functional consistent? If they are, how are they consistent? If they are consistent, then can we make cross-statements like the proto-theorem?

Comment: The motivation for this is that the variational approach of minimizing the free-energy density exactly reproduces the groundstate degeneracy calculated in "Superconductors are Topologically Ordered." I am wondering whether this is just a serendipitous coincidence.

Comment: Please 1) cite the papers you refer to, 2) make the question clear (the word *assumptions*  cited 5 times seems completely obscure to me / what do you call an assumptions, and what are they ?, difference between $F$ and $\tilde{F}$ is completely obscure, how could you compare a space-time with a space problem ? (providing I understood your undefined notations of course) 3) make clear what do you call a Ginzburg-Landau model (is it a classical Abelian Higgs model, or an effective theory for small complex order parameter ? / is it in space-time or in space only ?). Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it may help you, the Ginzburg-Landau functional is an artificial, heuristic construction whose minimisation tells us that : i) the ground state of a superconductor can be represented by a complex order-parameter, ii) the phase of the complex order parameter is related to electromagnetism. To my knowledge, it has been justified in only one limit : close to the critical temperature, see Gor'kov paper of 1959, Sov. Phys JETP vol. 36, p.1364. There is no other justification from the mean-field theory as far as I know. One can nevertheless uses the GL model, and ask experiments to justify it.